# Check if str_replace Should Execute First to Avoid Duplicate Strings

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Each time we save our ACF form, this snippet adds additional  tags around the registered trademark symbol. Our goal is for it to do it just once, so we need to check for the tags first but don't know how, as we're quite new to PHP.

```
function superscript_R( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
if( is_string($value) ) {
    $value = str_replace(['®', '&reg;'],'<sup>®</sup>',  $value );
}
return $value;
}

// Apply to all fields
add_filter('acf/update_value', 'superscript_R', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check first if string contains  and if it does just don't replace.

```
function superscript_R( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
   if( is_string($value) && strpos($value, '<sup>') === false ) {
       $value = str_replace(['®', '&reg;'],'<sup>®</sup>',  $value );
   }
   return $value;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks a bunch, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `$value` if it contains the symbol or not. So, it will replace the values only if it doesn't have the `<sup>®</sup>`

```
if( is_string($value) && strpos($value, '<sup>®</sup>') === false ) {
    $value = str_replace(['®', '&reg;'],'<sup>®</sup>',  $value );
}
```

Comment: should be `strpos($value, '<sup>®</sup>' ) === false` not `strpos($value, '<sup>®</sup>' ) == 0`

Comment: Thanks @Maximus, I was editing my answer, while you added your comment. I added an exclamation mark in front of it instead of === false

Comment: it will still not work because strpos can return `0`. You should use strict type check.